# Getting Hidden Achievement Description From Steam API

Tags: steam

The endpoint for [`GetSchemaForGame`](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUserStats#GetSchemaForGame) allows for access to a games achievements. The description field is missing from any hidden achievements. Is there any way to obtain this value? Perhaps some undocumented parameter that is provided in the request.

[`GetPlayerAchievements`](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerAchievements_.28v0001.29)

Comment: Isn’t the whole point that they are hidden?

Comment: This should probably be asked on Stackoverflow rather than here.  Unfortunately from what I can tell the answer is "no"

Comment: @Topcode Yes, but as soon you unlocked the achievement, the description is shown. So, where is this coming from?

Comment: [Steam Achievement Manager](https://github.com/gibbed/SteamAchievementManager/blob/7b301fa56acb7f1130a0a2a24368c4f3da3ebe1b/SAM.Game/Manager.cs#L341) doesn't seem to be capable (it's [using it's own GetLocalizedString](https://github.com/gibbed/SteamAchievementManager/blob/7b301fa56acb7f1130a0a2a24368c4f3da3ebe1b/SAM.Game/Manager.cs#L196) with the last value being the default, which is "" at line 341), so I don't believe it's going to be possible.